# Multiple Ubuntu servers - quick stats

Tags: ubuntu, statistics

I recently learned about Ubuntu Landscape - but for my purpose it's an overkill, and seems that it's not free.

I have 3 servers, and I want to visit a single website that gives me a quick summary of the load of those servers. Same information that can be obtained by `top`, `uptime` and `who`.

Is there something already available server/client?

Comment: I've often wondered this too. Maybe I shall go after this bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Is there something already available server/client?***

Certainly, yes.

Here's what I've found on the subject... There are many options, as you might expect. And certainly more than those I've found and listed here..

### Munin

As [explained here](http://www.debianadmin.com/monitor-servers-and-clients-using-munin-in-ubuntu.html):

> Munin the tool surveys all your computers and remembers what it saw.
>   It presents all the information in in graphs through a web interface.
>   Its emphasis is on plug and play capabilities. After completing a
>   installation a high number of monitoring plugins will be playing with
>   no more effort. Using Munin you can easily monitor the performance of
>   your computers, networks, SANs, and quite possibly applications as
>   well. It makes it easy to determine “what’s different today” when a
>   performance problem crops up.

Munin is available from apt. Personally, I'd try Munin first.

### Nagios2

As [explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nagios2):

> Nagios is an open source host, service and network monitoring program.
>   It is composed by the main service and a set of plugins which makes it
>   very flexible as they can be developed by anyone. Nagios provides a
>   web interface for the user to monitor but it also is capable of
>   sending emails or even messages to a pager in case of problems.

You can install it via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install nagios2 nagios-plugins nagios-images
```

There are some additional configuration steps to follow, please refer to the above link.

*Alternatively...*

### Logwatch

As [explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logwatch):

> Logwatch is a tool that will monitor your server's logs and email the
>   administrator a digest on a daily basis.

Logwatch is also available from apt:

```
sudo apt-get install logwatch
```

Note that you'll also need to setup sendmail or something so it can email you reports.

If I were to make my own server monitoring web application, I may use logwatch as a part of a backend for that...

### Cacti

As [explained here](http://www.cacti.net/):

> Cacti is a complete network graphing solution designed to harness the
>   power of RRDTool's data storage and graphing functionality. Cacti
>   provides a fast poller, advanced graph templating, multiple data
>   acquisition methods, and user management features out of the box. All
>   of this is wrapped in an intuitive, easy to use interface that makes
>   sense for LAN-sized installations up to complex networks with hundreds
>   of devices.